# Can I use a local path to json with Google Maps API

Tags: json, google-maps-api-3, local

Per the documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-data-simple):

Can I replace:

```
map.data.loadGeoJson('https://storage.googleapis.com/maps-devrel/google.json');
```

with a local path such as:

> C:\path\file.json ?

or must it be hosted on a server?
Thanks

Comment: I think "C:\path\file.json" won't work. https://developers.google.com/maps/tutorials/data/importing_data#loading_data_from_a_local_file

Answer (score 0):

In general, this **used to be not allowed by design**. It's a violation of the sandbox.

From Wikipedia -> Javascript -> Security:

*JavaScript and the DOM provide the potential for malicious authors to deliver scripts to run on a client computer via the web. Browser authors contain this risk using two restrictions. First, scripts run in a sandbox in which they can only perform web-relatedactions, not general-purpose programming tasks like creating files.*

**However, it's now possible in current browsers using the FILE API specification.**

This should in theory allow you to read it using the **FileReader** interface, although you might need to use something like **JSON.parse()** (or **$.parseJSON** if you're using JQuery) to then interpret it in the way you need. Lots more detail and examples of how to do this are here:

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/

Comment: does not load the json into google maps. When I enter the local path to the json into the browser, it loads the text, so the browser can read it.

Comment: Hi, it's possible that you might have to call the file using the script tag because that has different permissions when it comes to calling files from different locations. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: I'm getting error: [10:07:17.634] NS_ERROR_DOM_BAD_URI: Access to restricted URI denied @ https://maps.gstatic.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/api-3/16/4/main.js:178

Comment: I made the call to the object array as such: map.data.loadGeoJson(jsonstr);

Comment: Hi, I've done a bit more research into this and think I've found the correct way to do it, although unfortunately it's not quite as simple as we'd hoped. I've updated my answer to point you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I was thinking jquery would be the answer as well